# Which way is the best to save file on external storage on Android?

Tags: android, android-external-storage

Which way is the best to save file on external storage...

a) `new File(Enviroment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "")`

b) `new File("/mnt/sdcard/","")`

Comment: First read this: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Comment: Both are same but always try to use Enviroment.getExternalStorageDirectory()...Eg: new File(Enviroment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"");

Comment: Both are not the same, who knows - maybe your external storage **is not** mounted at **/sdcard** ? So prefer a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always use

```
 Enviroment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
```

instead of hard coding as below...

```
/mnt/sdcard/
```

If you choose hard coding way then the system will throw you below message...

```
Do not hardcode "/sdcard/"; use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() instead
```

**Another problem** is that `SDCard` folder name isn't same for all devices...`SDCard` name different in Some devices.

In samsung devices, it is named `external_sd` and in this case, the hard coding way will be failed. That's why following way is the best...

```
File file = new File(Enviroment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), "");
```

Answer (score 3):

Enviroment.getExternalStorageDirectory() is the best way to save file into external storage.
Take a look at this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html

Answer (score 0):

Always use

```
Enviroment.getExternalStorageDirectory() in place of mnt/sdcard/
```

Answer (score 0):

`Enviroment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` is the best public API for directly accessing the SD card.

However, you should consider using the new `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` intent which allows the user to select a location for saving.

For example, if a device has multiple SD cards, the user can select between them, or they can choose any app participating in the Storage Access Framework.